# how to code to_s (toString) method for Linked list

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a singly Linked List in Ruby and it works fine until I try to delete all the elements to the list. Deleting the elements seems to work but deleting the last element and calling a `to_s` method causes a runtime error even though I tried to traverse the list while the next Item is not equal to nil.

Here's my code:

```
#----- NODE CLASS -----#
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :link  # automatically generated getters & setters

  # Constructor/Initializer #
  def initialize(data = nil, link = nil)
      @data = data
      @link = link
  end

  # toString method #
  def to_s
    @data
  end 
end #End node class


#----- AbstractList Class -----#
class AbstractList
  @@listSize

  def getSize
    return @@listSize

  end

  # Constructor/Initializer #
  def initialize()
   @head = nil 
   @@listSize = 0
  end

  # insert at the front of the list #
  def insertFront(item)
    if @head == nil
      @head = Node.new(item)
    else
      temp = Node.new(item)
      temp.link = @head
      @head = temp
    end
    @@listSize += 1
  end

  # insert at the front of the list #
  def insertBack(item)
    if @head == nil
      @head = Node.new(item)
    else
      current = @head

      while current.link != nil
        current = current.link
      end 
      newNode = Node.new(item, nil)
      current.link = newNode
    end
    @@listSize += 1
  end

  # remove from the front of the list #    
  def removeFront()
    if empty()
      raise "List is empty"
    end
    current = @head
    @head = @head.link
    current = nil
    @@listSize -= 1
  end  

  # check if list is empty # 
  def empty()
    result = false
    if @@listSize == 0
      result = true
    end
    return result
  end


  # toString method #
  def to_s
    result = []
    current = @head

    while current.link != nil 
      result << current.data
      current = current.link
    end
    result << current.data
    return result
  end

end #End AbstractList class


#----- MAIN METHOD -----#
#node = Node.new("Ten", "twenty")
#print node.to_s

list = AbstractList.new()
list.insertFront("One")
list.insertFront("Two")
list.insertFront("Three")
list.insertFront("Four")

list.insertBack(10)
list.insertBack(20)
list.insertBack(30)
list.insertBack(40)

print list.to_s 
puts "  List size => #{list.getSize}"

list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()
list.removeFront()

print list.to_s
puts "  List size => #{list.getSize}"

list.removeFront()
```

It prints out the following and causes an error when I remove the last element and print:

```
>["Four", "Three", "Two", "One", 10, 20, 30, 40]  List size => 8
>[40]  List size => 1
>List size => 0
>in `to_s': undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

and the error points to the line

```
while current.link != nil
```

in the `to_s` method of the Abstract list.

Comment: FWIW `empty` can be reduced to `def empty return @@listSize == 0 end`

Comment: I'd say that `empty` _should be_ reduced to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When last element is deleted then `@head` is set to `nil`
Now, you are calling `to_s` on list

```
def to_s
  result = []
  current = @head

  while current.link != nil 
    result << current.data
    current = current.link
  end
  result << current.data
  return result
end
```

Here `current = @head` which is assigned to `nil`

In next step,  `while current.link != nil` , it will check `link` for `nil` which is throwing an error.

Solution :  change your while condition to `while current and current.link != nil`

```
def to_s
  result = []
  current = @head

  while current and current.link != nil 
    result << current.data
    current = current.link
  end
  result << current.data if current
  return result
end
```

Comment: Rather than prompt the OP to accept an answer under your own answer you should allow 24 hours to pass, then, if the OP hasn't selected an answer, add a comment under the _question_ not the answer. It's not to the OPs advantage to select quickly, nor does it help Stack Overflow.